# How do I upgrade one of the subpackages in golang?

Tags: go

E.g., github security alery signaled:

> Upgrade github.com/opencontainers/runc to version 1.0.0-rc95 or later. For example:

How can I do it in golang with minimal code changes? This package is not being declared in `go.mod` (seems like it's indirect dependency).

When I run `go get -u`, I can see a whole bunch of undirect dependencies added to my `go.mod` which is a bit overkill:

```
require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.N.0 // indirect <--------
```

Is there a way to update directy that dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure `go get -u github.com/opencontainers/runc` should do it.